# Is it possible to have a link invisible/hidden in webpage source but active when button click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hey guys I was wondering, is it possible to have a link invisible/hidden in webpage source but active when a button is clicked?
Why do I want this? Because i'm creating a webpage sort of game but I don't want the user to be able to just right click and see the source code (I don't mean disabling right click) so they can just see the next URL and manually enter it into the web browser to get to the next page/level, I want it to be given to them when they finish the challenge and click the submit button.
Sorry if I didn't explain this to easily, if you didn't quite understand, just say and i will try rephrase what i am trying to say :)

BTW preferably in Jquery including PHP

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
  function TheFunction(answer) {
    if (answer == "theanswer") {
      alert("Well done, time for level 2.");
      location.href = "<?php echo "hi"; ?>.php"; // <-- or somthing like this
    }
    else {
        alert("Wrong answer.");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by link being active?

Comment: I mean have the link appear in the code so the page knows where to redirect to :)

Comment: Yes it is, store the URL on the server and get it when needed, anything stored on the clientside is accessible to the client.

Comment: as @adeneo said, it is possible by storing on the esrver what you need. Just a little idea: instead of verifying from the client if the answer is correct, do an AJAX request to a PHP script by passing the answer, check it, and answer or redirect through PHP :)

Comment: The point is the user is suppose to look through the src of the website to find the answer in the JS (Yes its a strange game XD ), so I need that part visible (The JS) but i want to redirect link invisable/hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XMLHttpRequests (AJAX) to fetch the next URL from a PHP-script, like the following:

```
$urls = array(
    1 => 'myGame1.php',
    2 => 'thisIsPage2.php',
    3 => 'iLikeJavaScript.html'
);

if (isset($_POST['nextPageUrl']), is_int($_POST['nextPageUrl'])) {
    echo $urls[$_POST['nextPageUrl']];
}
```

In this example you have an array with all the URLs inside and echo just the one you need. Alternatively you are able to load the next page from the database, generate a new random file, whatever you need.

On your javascript side of things, you use something like this (assuming you are using jQuery, "normal" javascript is also possible, just a bit more complicated):

```
function TheFunction(answer) {
    if (answer == "theanswer") {
        alert("Well done, time for level 2.");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'yourPage.php', 
            data: { nextPageUrl: 2 }
        }).done(function (msg) {
            location.href = msg;
        });
    }
    else {
        alert("Wrong answer.");
    }
}
```

---

This is just an approach to the actual solution. Every client-side validation can be bypassed, therefore you might as well check the answer in the PHP-file, just to make sure someone isn't manually performing the AJAX request.

This could simply be done by modifying the PHP-file, and passing the answer to the script via ajax (expanding the `data`-object).

```
$urls = array(
    1 => array('url' => 'myGame1.php', 'answer' => 'theanswer'),
    2 => array('url' => 'thisIsPage2.php', 'answer' => 'theanswer2'),
    3 => array('url' => 'iLikeJavaScript.html', 'answer' => 'theanswer3'),
);

if (isset($_POST['nextPageUrl']), is_int($_POST['nextPageUrl'])) {
    if ($urls[$_POST['nextPageUrl']]['answer'] == $_POST['thisAnswer'])
        echo $urls[$_POST['nextPageUrl']]['url'];
}
```

Comment: So far this seams like the best way, but still not 100% ideal as the user could just do a post request himself to return the webpage URL, Is there anyway you know of that could stop a user doing a post form his/her website to mine to return the URL?, but thank you for this answer :)

Comment: I've edited it and added an additional server-side validation to it. This way they are still able to access the page by themselves, but won't get the URL unless the answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to start with a webpage that simply does not contain the next button/link then make it so that when they finish the "challenge" the webpage changes to the version that does have the Next Challenge link.

Comment: Yes, this is what im wanting to do (in a way) but how?

Comment: When he game completes, move him to the similar URL that is exactly the same as the one before but only has the link added to it. I know the user can still go to this intermediary link then to the next lvl but it is hard to believe anyone would think a link exactly the same would move them to the next lvl.

Comment: Another way is to use a variable that increments itself (or changes) when the level is complete and the you just verify if the variable incremented and if it did it means the lvl is complete, so you can give him the next lvl then :)

Answer (score 0):

For do that you can can use javascript (jQuery : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp)

But this will not protect your webpage because people can always see the javascript. You had to protect your next page/level in php.

Comment: This wont work because users will still be able to see this source and be able to extract the link

Comment: You can just have 2 pages for each webpage one page for the level and one other for check if it's the good answer and use a Session (or a dataBase is you want to save the level for the next connexion) for be sure that he complete the level. Then you just have to check on each page if the session (or batabase) correspond with the level.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's possible...let's say you have a mysql database for example...
You must put your link in it...for example look at this code that I've written for ya:

```
$query = "select * from lnkstabl";
$res = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
echo '<a href="http://' . $row['link'] . '">go to link</a>';
```

Hope that I could solve your problem...

Comment: And it shows up in the HTML markup, therefore it's not what he wants.

Comment: Yes but wont this link be visible in the source when the webpage generates?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may be what you're thinking about:

On server side, create a file `JS.php` containing your javascript code like this:

```
echo '
  function Try(answer) {
    if (answer == "theanswer") {
      alert("Well done, time for level 2.");
      location.href = "<?php echo "hi"; ?>.php"; // <-- or somthing like this
    }
    else {
        alert("Wrong answer.");
    }
  }';
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
```

On client side

```
<script src="path/to/JS.php"></script>
```

Comment: And the user can look at the source code, click the link to the file and see the URL again.

Comment: Again though, users will just be able to follow the link and in the source "src="path/to/JS.php"" to then open up the JS.php and view the link that was just echoed in the JS.php?